# geb testing on ratpack and vuejs

Tags: javascript, geb, ratpack

I'm building a frontend using Ratpack and the asset-pipeline and am testing it using Geb. I require some of the pages to be dynamic, and as Knockoutjs seems to be no longer in development, I've been using VueJS. My problem is that while I'm able to visually see the data from my Vue model, my Geb tests break as the content isn't found. I've tried adding extra time, switching to different browsers (I mainly use PhantomJS,but have tried with Firefox and Chrome), and each time I'm not able to see the elements when it's running int this fashion. I could look away and continue developing, but that doesn't feel right if I can't at least validate the content is appearing on the page. I know Vue is relatively new, but I imagine the same might happen if you're using something using ReactJS. I've attached the relevant code parts below. What is the best way to test this?

*build.gradle*

```
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4", {
      exclude module: "groovy-all"
  }
  testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.10.0"
  // Geb integration

    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.51.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.51.0"
    testCompile("com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.2.1") {
        // phantomjs driver pulls in a different selenium version
        transitive = false
    }
```

*vuetest.gtpl*

```
    layout 'layouts/main.gtpl',                                   
    title: 'Vue Test',                                
    bodyContents: contents {
        div('id':'main'){
            p "The result is:"
            vuetest{}
        }

   }
```

*VueTest.js*

```
    Vue.component('vuetest', {
    template: '<p>Hello from Vue</p>'
})
```

*VueTestPage.groovy*

```
import geb.Page

class VueTestPage extends Page {

  static url = "/"

  static at = { title == "Vue Test" }

  static content = {
    vueGreeting(required:false){$('p',text:"Hello from Vue").text()}
  }
}
```

*geb test*

```
      def "vue testing"(){
    when:
    to VueTestPage
    then:
    at VueTestPage
    waitFor(vueGreeting.displayed) //fails
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Geb question. When I reproduced your steps I got a message saying:

`Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: displayed for class: java.lang.String`

Which makes sense given that you asked for `vueGreeting(required:false){$('p',text:"Hello from Vue").text()}`

You could either change the content to be `vueGreeting(required:false){$('p',text:"Hello from Vue")}` in order to use `vueGreeting.displayed`

or with original `vueGreeting` definition change spec to say

```
then:
waitFor {
    vueGreeting == 'Hello from Vue'
}
```